# Hibernate JPQL query is very slow compared to SQL

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpql

In my project I have a problem with one JPQL query which takes about 1,5s. When I execute SQL query copied from debug log (the same one which executes Hibernates) direct on PostgreSQL db it takes about 15ms.

```
@Service
@Transactional
@Slf4j
public class PersonSyncServiceImpl
        extends HotelApiCommunicationService implements PersonSyncService {
[...]
    private PersonLinked getLinkedPerson(CNPerson cnPerson, Obiekt obiekt) {
        PersonLinked person = cnPerson.getPersonLinked();
        if (person == null) {     
            var o = cnPerson;
            List<PersonLinked> personList = personLinkedDao.findPersonLinkedByRecordData(
                    o.getPersonImiona(), o.getPersonNazwisko(), o.getPersonPesel(), o.getPersonEmail(), o.getPersonTelefon1());            
            person = personList.stream()                
                    .findFirst().orElse(null);
            if (person == null) {
                person = createPersonLinkedFromCnPerson(cnPerson);
                personLinkedDao.save(person);
            }
            cnPerson.setPersonLinked(person);            
        }
        return person;
    }
[...]   
}
```

Problem is with this line:

```
List<PersonLinked> personList = personLinkedDao.findPersonLinkedByRecordData(
        o.getPersonImiona(), o.getPersonNazwisko(), o.getPersonPesel(), o.getPersonEmail(), o.getPersonTelefon1());
```

Dao with defined query:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface PersonLinkedDao extends JpaRepository<PersonLinked, Long> {

    @Query("select o from PersonLinked o \n" +
            "where o.personImiona = :imie and o.personNazwisko = :nazwisko \n" +
            "  and (o.personPesel = :pesel or o.personEmail = :email or o.personTelefon1 = :telefon)")
    List<PersonLinked> findPersonLinkedByRecordData(
                                                  @Param("imie") String personImiona,
                                                  @Param("nazwisko") String personNazwisko,
                                                  @Param("pesel") String personPesel,
                                                  @Param("email") String personEmail,
                                                  @Param("telefon") String personTelefon);
}
```

SQL from Hibernate debug log:

```
select [..]
from
    person personlinke0_ 
where
    personlinke0_.person_imiona=? 
    and personlinke0_.person_nazwisko=? 
    and (
        personlinke0_.person_pesel=? 
        or personlinke0_.person_email=? 
        or personlinke0_.person_telefon1=?
    )
```

When I execute this query on database it takes about 15ms, execution from code takes about 1,5s. I commented out this line in code and lag disappeared, so for sure problem is this jpql select.

Database connection configuration:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.200:5433/XXXXXXX
spring.datasource.username=XXXXX
spring.datasource.password=XXXXX
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
```

UPDATE 1:

debug.log:

```
26-09-2020 16:06:36.130 [http-nio-8091-exec-2] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL.logStatement - 
    select [...]
    from
        person personlinke0_ 
    where
        personlinke0_.person_imiona=? 
        and personlinke0_.person_nazwisko=? 
        and (
            personlinke0_.person_pesel=? 
            or personlinke0_.person_email=? 
            or personlinke0_.person_telefon1=?
        )
26-09-2020 16:06:36.130 [http-nio-8091-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doGetTransaction - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(1971671100<open>)] for JPA transaction
26-09-2020 16:06:36.130 [http-nio-8091-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.handleExistingTransaction - Participating in existing transaction
26-09-2020 16:06:36.146 [http-nio-8091-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doGetTransaction - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(1971671100<open>)] for JPA transaction
26-09-2020 16:06:36.146 [http-nio-8091-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.handleExistingTransaction - Participating in existing transaction
26-09-2020 16:06:36.146 [http-nio-8091-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doGetTransaction - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(1971671100<open>)] for JPA transaction
26-09-2020 16:06:36.146 [http-nio-8091-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.handleExistingTransaction - Participating in existing transaction
26-09-2020 16:06:37.521 [http-nio-8091-exec-2] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL.logStatement -
```

UPDATE 2:

PersonLinked entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@Getter
@Setter
@SuperBuilder
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "personId")
public class PersonLinked extends SCPerson {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "seq_person", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_person", sequenceName = "seq_person", allocationSize = 30)
    @Column(name = "OSOBA_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long personId;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "personLinked", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<CNPerson> cnPersonList;

    @Tolerate
    public PersonLinked() {
        super();
    }

    @PrePersist
    @Override
    protected void preInsert() {
        super.preInsert();
    }
}
```

SCPerson class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
@SuperBuilder
public class SCPerson {
[...]
}
```

Comment: How can you so sure this query only takes time or others operations ? and if you want top element only you can fetch only that.

Comment: @Eklavya I have enabled "logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG" in my config and I see it in log. Otherwise when I changed this line to "List<PersonLinked> personList = new ArrayList<>()" the lag disappeared.

Comment: Remove `@Transactional` in your repository. I believe that related to some other problems

Comment: How many rows in that table? You can fetch only the top one element using pageable rather fetching all data from table [Ex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44567102/4207306). Mapping all data into the entity takes time.

Comment: @Eklavya Table person is empty.

Comment: @ToànNguyễnHải When I commented out Transactional annotation now it takes longer - about 2,4s

Comment: hmm remove @Transactional on your service class, only add on specific method.

Comment: How is the PersonLinked entity mapped? It may be slow because of eager fetching too much entities or due to the N+1 problem.
In addition, I would suggest setting the spring.jpa.show-sql=true to true to see if there any any "hidden" queries.

Comment: @ToànNguyễnHải Removing Transactional annotation or moving it on the method didn't help.

Comment: @toucheqt That's not the N+1 problem, I analysed logs and this method executes only 3 SQL queries - two inserts (no problem) and this problematic select. I updated post and add entity class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution, problem was in another part of code.
Before calling method getLinkedPerson() I had this line of code:

```
List<CNPerson> cnPersonList = cnPersonDao.findCnPersonNotLinkedWithPerson(obiekt.getLoid());
```

cnPersonList constans here about 70 000 objects.

I changed it to:

```
List<Integer> ids = cnPersonDao.findCnPersonIdsNotLinkedWithPerson(obiekt.getLoid());
```

Problem is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46258045/9678458

> Slow down during Hibernate context refresh. In case when you update
> too many objects ORM engine (lets say Hibernate) has to sink them and
> keep them in memory. Literally Hibernate must have all old states and
> all new states of updated objects. Sometimes it does this quite
> unoptimal.
>
> You can indicate this using debug. Try to find the slowest place and
> check what exactly is being invoked there. I might guess that it slows
> down when hibernate updates state of the cache.

I think it is because entities CNPerson and PersonLinked are linked, but I am not sure:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
@JoinTable(name = "cnperson_links",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "cnperson_loid")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "person_id")})
private PersonLinked personLinked;
```